# Type inference & new in F#

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Using F# 2.0 and FSI I have the following:

```
let foo = List(xs)//works
let bar = new List(xs) //need type parameter 'The type System.Collectsion.Generic<_> expects 1 type argument 0 was given
```

now of course I can do:

```
let baz = new List<TypeOItemsInXs>(xs)//why?
```

Now is there something I reasonably can do?
Why do I have to choose between working type inference or warnings free code (if 'List' is disposable you get a warning that you should use 'new' to be explicit about it).

Any workaround? Is this a bug or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can still use type inference with a wildcard `_`:

```
open System.Collections.Generic
let xs = [1;2;3]

let bar = new List<_>(xs)
```

BTW, to distinguish F# list and .NET `List<T>` container, F# has renamed the .NET `List<T>` to `ResizeArray<T>`, which is in `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections` and this namespace is opened by default:

```
let bar2 = new ResizeArray<_>(xs)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yin Zhu answer is correct, I'd like to add one detail. In F# you can call .NET constructors with or without the `new` keyword. If `new` is omitted there's no need to add the generic parameter, but if you use `new` then you must add a generic parameter, even if you let type inference do the work using a wildcard `_`.

Thus, you can say:

```
> ResizeArray([1; 2; 3;]);;
val it : System.Collections.Generic.List<int> = seq [1; 2; 3]
```

or

```
> new ResizeArray<_>([1; 2; 3;]);;
val it : ResizeArray<int> = seq [1; 2; 3]
```

but not:

```
> new ResizeArray([1; 2; 3;]);;

  new ResizeArray([1; 2; 3;]);;
  ----^^^^^^^^^^^

C:\Temp\stdin(5,5): error FS0033: The type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ResizeArray<_>' expects 1 type argument(s) but is given 0
```

Comment: IMO this is even better. `new` is superfluous.

Comment: also, i think new should be used with the use keyword, when you are creating an IDisposable, otherwise it's should be omitted

Comment: yes my problem is that I have a disposable type, and omitting the new gives a warning. If I add the new then I as Yin Zhu points out can get away with using a wildcard. It just feels strange that the language is asymetric like that :S